# override clarity-ui.min.css with global style sheet

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

I new at angualr2 and i am trying to build a webpage using clarity.

I am trying to set the height of the main container `clr-main-container` to `min-height: 100vh;` in the `style.css` file that i placed in `~/src/style.css` this is where I set the global styles.

in the default clarity css file the styles are set to

```
.main-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fafafa;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

As i mentioned, I am trying to change `height: 100vh;` to `min-height: 100vh;` so in the style.css file i tried setting

```
.main-container {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

to override the default clarity css file but this isnt working with me.

I did include the style.css in the angilar-cli.json file.

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css",
        "../node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css",
        "../node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css",
        "../node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css",
        "../node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
      ],
```

but i am still having this issue. 
What am i missing?

Comment: Set `height: auto !important` as well. Could you also try moving `"styles.css"` entry to the last position in the `styles` array?

Comment: @SangeethSudheer  setting `height: auto !important` in the `styles.css` file solved what i was trying to do thank you :). it disabled the default height.

I did change the `styles` position to last before but it didn't work so i kept it the same. it works now anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override CSS rules either by being more specific, or by adding `!important` as @SangeethSudheer suggested.

It is always more elegant and flexible to use the first option, being more specific, and only use `!important` as a last resort.

**More specific CSS rules**

```
/* global (less specific) */

.active { 
    height: auto;
}

/* more specific, will override the above */

div.active {
    height: 50vh;
}

header div.active {
    height: 10vh;
}
```